# Iterate deeply nested object values and put them in a separate variable

Tags: javascript, algorithm, object, methods, iteration

Let's say there is an object that looks like this:

**Data object**

```
const movies = {
  action: {
    actionMovie1: {
      title: "Action Movie 1", // <-- Move to the separate object
      rating: 5,
    },
    actionMovie2: {
      title: "Action Movie 2", // <-- Move to the separate object
      rating: 5,
    },
    actionMovie3: {
      title: "Action Movie 3", // <-- Move to the separate object
      rating: 5,
    },
  },

  adventure: {
    adventureMovie1: {
      title: "Adventure Movie 1", // <-- Move to the separate object
      rating: 5,
    },
    adventureMovie2: {
      title: "Adventure Movie 2", // <-- Move to the separate object
      rating: 5,
    },
    adventureMovie3: {
      title: "Adventure Movie 3", // <-- Move to the separate object
      rating: 5,
    },
  },

  animated: {
    new: {
      newAnimatedMovie1: {
        title: "New Animated Movie 1", // <-- Move to the separate object
        rating: 5,
      },
      newAnimatedMovie2: {
        title: "New Animated Movie 2", // <-- Move to the separate object
        rating: 5,
      },
    },
    reviewed: {
      reviewedAnimatedMovie1: {
        title: "Reviewed Animated Movie 1", // <-- Move to the separate object
        rating: 5,
      },
      reviewedAnimatedMovie2: {
        title: "Reviewed Animated Movie 2", // <-- Move to the separate object
        rating: 5,
      },
    },
  },
};
```

Now I'm trying to iterate a data object, collect all the movie titles and put them in a separate object so that the final result looks something like this:

**Expected result**

```
const movieTitles = {
  actionMovie1: "Action Movie 1",
  actionMovie2: "Action Movie 2",
  actionMovie3: "Action Movie 3",

  adventureMovie1: "Adventure Movie 1",
  adventureMovie2: "Adventure Movie 2",
  adventureMovie3: "Adventure Movie 3",

  newAnimatedMovie1: "New Animated Movie 1",
  newAnimatedMovie2: "New Animated Movie 2",

  reviewedAnimatedMovie1: "Reviewed Animated Movie 1",
  reviewedAnimatedMovie2: "Reviewed Animated Movie 2",
};
```

So far, the closest result I could get was with this method, but it only works for the first two keys.

**Current attempt**

```
const movieTitles = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.values(movies).flatMap((movie) =>
    Object.entries(movie).map(([key, value]) => [key, value.title])
  )
);
```

Could you please help complete this function, given the fact that more data may be added in the future. For example, later the data object might look like this:

**Updated data object**

```
const movies = {
  action: {
    actionMovie1: {
      title: "Action Movie 1",
      rating: 5,
    },
    actionMovie2: {
      title: "Action Movie 2",
      rating: 5,
    },
    actionMovie3: {
      title: "Action Movie 3",
      rating: 5,
    },
    actionMovie4: { // <-- New, follows the same structure
      title: "Action Movie 4",
      rating: 5,
    },
  },

  adventure: {
    adventureMovie1: {
      title: "Adventure Movie 1",
      rating: 5,
    },
    adventureMovie2: {
      title: "Adventure Movie 2",
      rating: 5,
    },
    adventureMovie3: {
      title: "Adventure Movie 3",
      rating: 5,
    },
    adventureMovie4: { // <-- New, follows the same structure
      title: "Adventure Movie 4",
      rating: 5,
    },
  },

  animated: {
    new: {
      newAnimatedMovie1: {
        title: "New Animated Movie 1",
        rating: 5,
      },
      newAnimatedMovie2: {
        title: "New Animated Movie 2",
        rating: 5,
      },
      newAnimatedMovie3: { // <-- New, follows the same structure
        title: "New Animated Movie 3",
        rating: 5,
      },
    },
    reviewed: {
      reviewedAnimatedMovie1: {
        title: "Reviewed Animated Movie 1",
        rating: 5,
      },
      reviewedAnimatedMovie2: {
        title: "Reviewed Animated Movie 2",
        rating: 5,
      },
      reviewedAnimatedMovie3: { // <-- New, follows the same structure
        title: "Reviewed Animated Movie 3",
        rating: 5,
      },
    },
    translated: { // <-- New category, follows the same structure
      translatedAnimatedMovie1: { // <-- New, follows the same structure
        title: "Translated Animated Movie 1",
        rating: 5,
      },
    },
  },
};
```

**New expected result**

```
const movieTitles = {
  actionMovie1: "Action Movie 1",
  actionMovie2: "Action Movie 2",
  actionMovie3: "Action Movie 3",
  actionMovie4: "Action Movie 4",

  adventureMovie1: "Adventure Movie 1",
  adventureMovie2: "Adventure Movie 2",
  adventureMovie3: "Adventure Movie 3",
  adventureMovie4: "Adventure Movie 4",

  newAnimatedMovie1: "New Animated Movie 1",
  newAnimatedMovie2: "New Animated Movie 2",
  newAnimatedMovie3: "New Animated Movie 3",

  reviewedAnimatedMovie1: "Reviewed Animated Movie 1",
  reviewedAnimatedMovie2: "Reviewed Animated Movie 2",
  reviewedAnimatedMovie3: "Reviewed Animated Movie 3",

  translatedAnimatedMovie1: "Translated Animated Movie 1",
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't know what sort of possible categories there'll be, it looks like you'll need to check, when iterating over an object, whether it has a `title` property - and if not, then it's a new category, rather than a movie, and so you need to iterate over the whole category.

While this is *possible* by returning an array of entries to turn into an object, while not flattening quite all the way to keep the entry arrays, I think a more imperative recursive function would make more sense.

```js
const movies={action:{actionMovie1:{title:"Action Movie 1",rating:5},actionMovie2:{title:"Action Movie 2",rating:5},actionMovie3:{title:"Action Movie 3",rating:5},actionMovie4:{title:"Action Movie 4",rating:5}},adventure:{adventureMovie1:{title:"Adventure Movie 1",rating:5},adventureMovie2:{title:"Adventure Movie 2",rating:5},adventureMovie3:{title:"Adventure Movie 3",rating:5},adventureMovie4:{title:"Adventure Movie 4",rating:5}},animated:{new:{newAnimatedMovie1:{title:"New Animated Movie 1",rating:5},newAnimatedMovie2:{title:"New Animated Movie 2",rating:5},newAnimatedMovie3:{title:"New Animated Movie 3",rating:5}},reviewed:{reviewedAnimatedMovie1:{title:"Reviewed Animated Movie 1",rating:5},reviewedAnimatedMovie2:{title:"Reviewed Animated Movie 2",rating:5},reviewedAnimatedMovie3:{title:"Reviewed Animated Movie 3",rating:5}},translated:{translatedAnimatedMovie1:{title:"Translated Animated Movie 1",rating:5}}}};

const movieTitles = {};
const getTitles = (parent) => {
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(parent)) {
    if (value.title) {
      movieTitles[key] = value.title;
    } else {
      getTitles(value);
    }
  }
};
getTitles(movies);
console.log(movieTitles);
```

Comment: That's a great solution, thank you! By the way, do you know maybe what would be an appropriate TypeScript typing for a function parameter (in this case `parent`) so that when we, for example, export the `movieTitles` object, we get automatic suggestions about the properties that exists in it?

Comment: I guess you could do `type Movie = { title: string; rating: number; };
interface MovieObj extends Record<string, MovieObj | Movie>{}`, but to have such a structure in the first place is pretty ugly. Better to have the actual movies be inside an array, instead of a plain object.